# What word to use to mean that someone accidentally hindered someone?

Tags: word-choice

Here is the context:

> The goalkeeper was trying to catch the ball, but a fellow player **accidentally hindered** him from doing it.

Is there a word in English meaning be in someone's way accidentally and by the way is the expression *hinder someone accidentally* natural?

Comment: No. That's why we have the words **accidentally** and **unintentionally** and other locutions to indicate that an action was not on purpose. I'm curious, do you have such a word in your native language?

Comment: No I we don't have such a word. I was curious if english had

Comment: Do you mean a fellow teammate?

Comment: Yes, I do mean fellow teammate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase **hindered her accidentally** is grammatical but not really natural if by "natural" you mean "conversational". It would be natural to say **he accidentally got in her way** or **he accidentally blocked her path  (or blocked her from {doing something})**.

> The goalie was going for the ball but a defender got in his way.